# SSIS: how to use date, selected in Execute SQL Task 1, and use it in Execute SQL Task 2

Tags: sql-server, ssis

It seems to be easy task, but I have been struggeling with this quite a while. I have "Execute SQL Task 1", where sql query result get me date, what I need to use in next "Execute SQL Task 2" in where condition.

I created variable "Date" with datatype "Object", also tried DateTime
"Execute SQL Task 1" I have set as following:
ResultSet = Single row
Under "Results Set" tab I have selected "Date" variable, what I want to passthrough to next SQL task.

"Execute SQL Task 2" - in SQLStatement I use this variable as ?
Under Parameter Mapping I have created mapping for parameter "Date" (Direction: Input, Data Type: Date(tried also others), Parameter name: 0, Parameter Size:-1)

But no luck so far, hopefully someone can give some good advice here :)

Comment: The object data type is for objects (like data sets) not scalar values. make your `Date` variable a datetime datatype, and map the column in your result setto the varaiable in your first Execute SQL Task to it; then use it in your second.

Answer (score 0):

In the  "Execute SQL Task 1", under the Result Set tab the Result Name should be the same as the column name that is returned by the query.

Example: If "Execute SQL Task 1" executes the query 'Select GETDATE() as MySystemDate', then the "Result Set" tab should be set as follows:

```
 Result Name - 'MySystemDate' 
 Variable Name - User::Date
```